# How to use singleton in obj-c/ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton

I've created a singleton (called sharedinstance) in my appDelegate, and ideally I want to access it from all other objects/instances in my code, but everytime I want to access a method/var in it, I'm having to do

```
Game *sharedInstance = [Game sharedInstance];
```

In whatever method in any other instance to be able to do something like..

```
[sharedInstance.myMethod]
```

I tried putting

```
Game *sharedInstance;
```

in the .h file of the other instance, but when I run the code, Game = 0. I just tried putting

```
Game *sharedInstance = [Game sharedInstance];
```

In the other instances init method but that's not helping either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not really related to singletons, it's just a matter of not knowing how to declare and use variables and methods. You need to get the instance of Game to call a method on it, you do this with [Game sharedInstance]. You then need to either call the method on it, or assign it to an instance variable to call a method later.

i.e. either:

```
[[Game sharedInstance] method]
```

or

```
(in the .h)
Game *sharedInstance

(in the init method in your .m)
sharedInstance = [Game sharedInstance];

(elsewhere in your .m)
[sharedInstance method];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Init method of your .m file use this

```
[[Game sharedInstance] method];
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...everytime I want to access a method/var in it, I'm having to do...

Yes. Before you use an object, whether it's a shared object like a singleton or not, you have to get a reference to it. Calling your singleton's `-sharedInstance` method is one way to do that. Another option would be to declare a global variable that points to the singleton, but given that singletons are often used as a fancy substitute for global variables that seems like a poor idea.